# l20n.js: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: element.querySelectorAll is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, l20n

I'm using Mozilla's l20n.js v. 3.5.0

```
<script defer src="/bower_components/l20n/dist/compat/web/l20n.js"></script>
```

and get a serious error, when script tries to parse the page.

```
l20n.js:2274 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: element.querySelectorAll is not a function(…)
getTranslatables @ l20n.js:2274
_translateFragment @ l20n.js:2341
(anonymous function) @ l20n.js:2067
translateRoots @ l20n.js:2066
translateView @ l20n.js:2623
(anonymous function) @ l20n.js:2491
```

Does anyone experience the same problem? Error thrown in both Chrome and Edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [a bug](https://github.com/l20n/l20n.js/commit/2afdfebce90565ffd19288560342d074733e255b) in the library. It was corrected but the new version is not published yet.

If you want you can correct the JavaScript file directly by replacing the content of `translateRoots()`, lines 2066-2068, by the following code:

```
var roots = Array.from(observers.get(view).roots);
return Promise.all(roots.map(function(root) { 
    _translateFragment(view,root) 
}));
```

**Update (26/2/2016)**: as stated in the comment below, now you just have to move to v3.5.1 or higher. It worked for me with FF, IE11, Chrome.

Comment: Version [3.5.1](https://github.com/l20n/l20n.js/releases/tag/v3.5.1) fixes this.  Thanks for the patience!

Comment: @StaśMałolepszy thank you, bower updated my project automatically this afternoon.